# Read with OpenCV 9 frames of a video while the 10th is processing

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, face-recognition

I have a program to detect faces in python, it makes the detection using the  [face_recognition library](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition) and then to the 90% of the frames use a tracking algorithm, it performs these operations each determined number of frames, in my case 10, but because of the resolution of the video it does not goes as fast as necessary. From that I have thought of 3 main paths to follow:

1. Make greater the number of frames to detect, which will make worse the general detection, which is not desired.
2. Reduce the quality of the video, which will decrease the detection rate, not desired neither.
3. Make a thread that reads 1 out of 10 frames and computes the detection, while the main program is reading the rest of the frames and performing the tracking. I do not know if this is possible. What I have found is the possibility of reading the frame I want using:

   ```
   cap.set(1, 100)
   ret, frame = cap.read()
   ```

What I do not know if it is possible to do is the threads parts as I have only found information about introducing arguments to threads but not receiving them. And in the case that the thread performs both the computation and the drawing I would need a flag to signal the moment of showing or writing the frame.